# Can I send a int by serialPort in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

Can I send a int by serialPort in C# ?

A developed a app in C# that send a data by serial port for arduino. This data is a comand that just can be a int ! Not a String ! 
How can i do this ? I read something bytes but a don´t undertsand.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

pulic class senddata(){

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
//Define a Porta Serial
    serialPort1.PortName = textBox2.Text;
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.Open();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     serialPort1.Write("1");  // "1" is a string, but i put 1 (int) give me a error.       
}

}
```

The arduino code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

void setup()
{
    servo.attach(9);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available())
    {

      int cmd = (unsigned char)Serial.read();

      if(cmd == 91){
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To write a 4-byte integer, with value `1`, you need to convert it to a a byte-array first.
I do this with `BitConverter`.  You can also do it with `Convert.ToByte`, as shown by @sll.

Note that it is very important to specify how many bytes you want to send to the serial port.

A 4-byte int? 2-bytes?  a single byte?
It doesn't seem that you specified that in your question.

```
int MyInt = 1;

byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt);
serialPort1.Write(b,0,4);
```

Comment: That will write a 32 bit integer, but the code expects an 8 bit integer (char in C).

Comment: @FredVaz:  You should start accepting answers to your questions.  Please check the "CheckMark" next to the answer you like best.

Comment: @Guffa:  As I mentioned, I didn't see anything in the question that specified if he wanted a single byte or a 4-byte integer.  But the change is pretty trivial.

Comment: @abelenky: If it actually is a multi-byte value, then you also need to know if it's in little-endian or big-endian format.

Comment: 8bit integer = one byte?? so why not just create a array of one byte and write that???

Answer (score 2):

You can use an other overload method:  ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551.aspx))

```
public void Write(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

```cs
// number should be positive value less than 256
int number = 20;
byte[] buffer = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(number) };
serialPort.Write(buffer, 0, 1);
```

This will write out single byte from a buffer